# Angular CLI, post request to a local API, returning null

Tags: json, angular, api, post, angular-cli

I have asked this question before, but I think I might have narrowed down the possibilities of errors, so I am asking again while being more specific.

I am trying to implement this post request to a local API in an angular app, but it only returns null. The API is working fin on its own, most of the code seems to be working in my app, but there is obviously something missing which makes it not work.

It seems that my code is calling the api successfully because if I test it using a string instead of an object (which the API is expecting), I get an error message in the console where I launched the API in parallel with `npm start`

So here is my code where I prompt the user to enter a string, and the code where I convert the string into an object and try to pass it into my post request.

1/`app.component.html`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Enter your String bellow:';
  result;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    onSubmit(textEnter: string) {
      let json = {
      "string": textEnter
    };

      console.log(json);
      return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/parentheses/', json).toPromise().then((data:any) => {
        console.log("testing");
        this.result = data.json;
      });
    }
}
```

2/ `app.components.ts`

```
<div>
  <form>
     <input #textEnter placeholder="text">
     <button type="submit" (click)="onSubmit(textEnter.value)">click here</button>
  </form>

  <pre>
    {{ (result | async) | json }}
  </pre>

</div>
```

I also created a `proxy.config.json` file:

```
{
  "/parentheses":{
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel1": "debug"
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try removing the async pipe, you're not returning an observable. `{{result | json}}`

Comment: my first guess would be to look at xss issues. you are posting to port 3000 but I bet your app was served from a different local port and you are accessing it via http://localhost:4321 or something like that different from port 3000

Comment: Either way, the value is initially undefined and you're not dealing with that in the template. You should type your properties so it's more obvious what's going on and the compiler can actually help you. Also components generally shouldn't access the `HttpClient` directly, and I'd recommend leaning into observables.

Comment: Thank you for your help guys!
@Sam, nope that didn't work. As a matter of fact it is not returning ```null``` anymore, but nothing at all.
@Max I created a proxy file, I added it in my question. Shouldn't that do the trick?
@jonsharpe, OK I will have to look into that, thatnks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code as follow. In your code you are using async pipe in the html code. But the 'result' variable is not an observable typed one.

```
    export class AppComponent {
          title = 'Enter your String bellow:';
          result: Observable<any>;
        
          constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

          onSubmit(textEnter: string) {
              let json = { string: textEnter};
              this.result = this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/parentheses/', json);
          }
    }
```

OR

Change your HTML code like this. **But as your code its not required returning the** the http request.

```
<pre>
   {{ result | json }}
</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. But unfortunately it didn't work. I still get ```null```

Comment: Actually I am getting this: ```Type 'Promise<Object>' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<any>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more.

(property) AppComponent.result: Observable<any>```

Comment: You trying to save promise one to Observable typed variable. Please make sure not to use " .toPromise() ".

Comment: this.result = this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/parentheses/', json);